# No SSH (Connection refused) using raspbian with pixel

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, security

Recently I updated my Raspbian image from a very old image to new Raspbian with PIXEL. On old image I had a lot of trash so I just dd'd a new SD card and inserted it to the rpi- I use Raspberry Pi 3.

After setting up a WiFi connection I have noticed that I cannot ssh to the device.

What can be an issue here?

I have checked the connection and it is fine- I have done `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and it succeeded. I can even browse the internet using pi's web browser.
 The only thing is that ssh is not working.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `raspi-config` to enable SSH.

Previously the default value was "enabled" but in November 2016 this has been changed due to the security issues and the default value is now "disabled". For more info see [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/).

Alternative method is to place a file `ssh` in `/boot` partition of the SD card. Content of the file is not important.